# GIT pack objects died of signal 10

Tags: git, git-push

I was trying to push my changes today to remote repository and I get following error:

```
git push -u origin master
error: pack-objects died of signal 10
```

Commit and push yesterday worked fine, there were no changes in settings, nobody else committed or pushed to the repository and the commit is not huge, just about 10 files.

I am using **MacOS Sierra** - git version 2.9.3 (Apple Git-75),
Repository is GitLab 8.13.5 (Git 2.7.4)

The whole repository is just 33MB so no large files are included (not even in the commit). I am using SSH to access the repository.

`git config pack.threads 1` had no effect.

I also tried cloning remote to new location, editing one file, committing, pushing and that worked, so the problem should be with the specific commit.

Running git fsck is resulting in the same error:

```
git fsck
error: unable to open .git/objects/14: Interrupted system call
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Bus error: 10
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Try `git config pack.threads 1` and then push again

Comment: Signal #10 is `SIGBUS` on BSD-based Unix-like systems and `SIGUSR1` on Linux. What OS are you using?

Comment: Does a push work on a new clone of the repo? Trying to confirm if the problem is with this specific repo on your machine or something to do with your OS and/or git installation

Comment: What protocol are you using SSH or HTTPS? The commit that you are trying to push, does it have a large file?

Comment: @AshutoshJindal: I don't really know how to clone local repository and try to push it? Sorry, quite new to git.

Comment: @falnyr, I meant re-clone the remote repository in another location locally. And then try a push on this new clone. Can you post the exact command you use to push? Will answer a lot of my questions in the previous comments.

Comment: @falnyr did setting the threads to 1 work ?

Comment: Try running `git fsck`

Comment: tried @robertklep and no result

Comment: tried @exussum without success

Comment: can you do `strace git push` and post the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error:

```
error: unable to open .git/objects/14: Interrupted system call
```

is rather mysterious.  This should be a directory and `git fsck` *should* be able to open it without being interrupted.<sup>1</sup>  You might run:

```
ls -ld .git/objects/14
```

to verify that it *is* a directory, and if so, `ls -l .git/objects/14` to see what's in it (it should contain zero or more files with hash-IDs as names<sup>2</sup>).

The SIGBUS indicates some kind of internal bug in Git.  C programs get SIGBUS or SIGSEGV when they attempt to use memory addresses they were never granted in the first place, or that are otherwise invalid (see [Bus error vs Segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/q/838540/1256452) and note that the decision of which signal to deliver is both OS- and architecture-dependent, so that Linux on ARM, MIPS, or SPARC will behave differently from the same version of Linux on x86, for instance).  It seems likely that whatever is causing Git to be unable to read the objects stored in the repository is leading to Git's subsequent crash, but Git—or at the least, `git fsck`—is not *supposed* to *crash* due to bad repositories.  Using `git fsck` in particular is *supposed* to diagnose what's *wrong* with a bad repository.  And in any case, getting `EINTR` when opening a directory is unusual, at least.

If the files *are* non-local (found over a network), you might move them to local (on-disk) storage and see if that at least makes the problem go away.  This is not "fixing" the bug so much as simply "avoiding" it, but if that suffices.... :-)

---

<sup>1</sup>The one obvious path where this might *not* be the case is if the file or directory is not stored on the local disk, but rather over the network, such as on an AFP server.

<sup>2</sup>These names will be only 38 characters long, giving the *remaining part* of the hash ID after removing the leading `14`.  The `14` is implied by the fact that they are in `.git/objects/14/`.

Comment: Avoiding the problem did the trick. I should have pointed out that the directory was mounted over SSHFS and it actually is a CentOS 7 server. What I think could be the problem is that there were 2 unstaged files in the working copy with the same name "file.txt" and "File.txt" and my local drive is case insensitive so... probably?

Comment: This suggests there might be a bug in the sshfs implementation: it should probably restart system calls on SIGALRM, rather than interrupting them. The files with differing case will give you a different headache on the Mac: to work around it, create a file system on your local disk that is case-sensitive. Note that there are some bugs in some MacOS releases in this area; see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217915/how-to-create-a-case-sensitive-filesystem-in-10-11-1