# The Git process exit code 138 (interrupted by signal 10: SIGBUS)

Tags: git, push, apple-m1, git-commit

Every time, when I commit or push, this comment shows up.

I'm using company network for project folder(with co-workers), and we push project on gitlab.
Someone(including me) use m1(mac), others use windows(Not sure is this related o
r not ^^:)

My os: Mac m1(Sliicon)

Those 3 are what I tried to solve.

1. sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=524288
2. sudo sysctl -p
3. git config --global core.autocrlf true input

Please help me T.T

I appreciate who can tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please add the complete output as it can be very helpful. Also, you mentioned various platforms - which platform are you using? I assume not windows, but it is not clear if linux/macos/other, and the architecture (M1/Intel/other). Does this happen on other platforms as well? If so - which? You did mention a "project folder" over network, so this might be caused by filename case-sensitivity issues; Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40692677/2840436 as it might be relevant for your case.

Comment: A "SIGBUS" error normally indicates a bug in the program. Setting `kern.maxfilesperproc`extremely high like this is not a good idea in general (it's for very specific cases) but probably doesn't have much to do with the problem.

Comment: Perhaps a run with `GIT_TRACE=1 git blahblah` could shed some light.

Comment: @torek

How can I rollback that function, then? It's first time to use mac os so I'm not very familiar with this command.

Comment: You'd have to use another `sysctl` to restore it to whatever it used to be set to. I'm not sure what your particular Mac would have as the default, but would also revert to the default on a system reboot. (I have a mac and mine is currently at 24576.) It's not specifically terrible to raise it, but most processes will bump into their per-process limit at 256 or so file descriptors, and that's usually fine.

Comment: In any case, you might want to try installing a different release of Git (which one do you have? run `git version` or `git --version` to find out; I updated my brew-installed one recently so I now have 2.38.1 on my mac.)

Comment: @torek 
Same git version with you. 2.38.1 
I installed it yesterday via homebrew.

Comment: Make sure you have a build for the m1, or have installed all the Intel emulation software, then. (I have an older Intel-based mac here.)

Comment: @torek

Maybe this is caused my network drive was used via window os. I changed computer to mac recently, and access same network drive project. I guess That's why all project linked something wrong way in git.

I coudln't find the way to solve this, I chose deleting all cloned project and clone again.
That's is the only way escaping lost git access in very short time. 

Thank you anyway all who answered my question!