# git error: pack-objects died of signal 10

Tags: git, azure-devops

i'm trying to push my code to new repo in azure,

Any help appreciated

```
➜   git:(master): git push newrepo -v
Pushing to https://dev.azure.com/blablabla
error: pack-objects died of signal 10
error: pack-objects died of signal 10
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://dev.azure.com/blablabla'
```

Push repo getting an erorr

Comment: Hi, can you try the `git fsck` command mentioned in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690410/git-pack-objects-died-of-signal-10)?

Comment: Issue resolved, I'm new to git and was trying to do something wrong, I copied the repo manually from the Mac folder to another folder and was trying to push to the new repo, this gave me a hard time with a lot of errors, I figured out the correct way is to pull the old repo in a new folder and then add new repo then push and it worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved, I'm new to git and was trying to do something wrong, I copied the repo manually from the Mac folder to another folder and was trying to push to the new repo, this gave me a hard time with a lot of errors, I figured out the correct way is to pull the old repo in a new folder and then add new repo then push and it worked fine