# Getting a bus error in Assembly in-line programming x86

Tags: assembly, x86, bus

I stumbled upon an assembly programming challenge where I need to find why the following code gives a Bus Error when trying to run it. After much googling, I still can't figure out why.. My understanding of assembly x86 not great, any tips on finding the solution would be very appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
  asm("pushf\n"
      "orl $ 0x40000, (%esp)\n"
      "popf\n");

  *((int*) (((char*) malloc(5)) + 1)) = 23; // This line causes the Bus Error


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212466/what-is-a-bus-error

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I found the error: the "+1" after malloc(5)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you are setting a flag in the flags register. Flag 0x40000, aka bit 18 which according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register_%28computing%29 is

18 AC   Alignment check (486SX+ only)   X

If you search for "flag alignment check" you find  amongst others:

http://forum.soft32.com/linux2/Turn-x86-Alignment-Check-ftopict12003.html

I hope this sets you on the right track. But do you really have a 486SX?

Comment: Thank you, I have no idea if I have a 486SX is, but at least that put me on the right track. I will check for info about the flag.

Comment: Note that the alignment check bit of the flags register seems like a really cool idea, and could help you catch and fix non-portable misaligned accesses in your programs without building and testing them on more RISCy architectures. However, since the x86 abi only has `double`s aligned to 4 bytes and not 8, it leads to spurious `SIGBUS` on most floating point code... :-( This makes it just about impossible to use in practice unless you write a `SIGBUS` handler that checks if the exception was due to floating point load/store and works around it...