# C generic linked-list

Tags: c, generics, pointers, linked-list, malloc

I have a generic linked-list that holds data of type void* I am trying to populate my list with type struct employee, eventually I would like to destruct the object struct employee as well.

Consider this generic linked-list header file (i have tested it with type char*):

```
struct accListNode                 //the nodes of a linked-list for any data type
{
  void *data;                     //generic pointer to any data type
  struct accListNode *next;       //the next node in the list
};

struct accList                    //a linked-list consisting of accListNodes
{
  struct accListNode *head;
  struct accListNode *tail;
  int size;
};

void accList_allocate(struct accList *theList);           //allocate the accList and set to NULL
void appendToEnd(void *data, struct accList *theList);    //append data to the end of the accList
void removeData(void *data, struct accList *theList);         //removes data from accList
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Consider the employee structure

```
struct employee 
{ 
   char name[20]; 
   float wageRate; 
}
```

Now consider this sample testcase that will be called from main():

```
    void test2()
    {
      struct accList secondList;
      struct employee *emp = Malloc(sizeof(struct employee));
      emp->name = "Dan";
      emp->wageRate =.5;

      struct employee *emp2 = Malloc(sizeof(struct employee));
      emp2->name = "Stan";
      emp2->wageRate = .3;

      accList_allocate(&secondList);
      appendToEnd(emp, &secondList);
      appendToEnd(emp2, &secondList);

      printf("Employee: %s\n", ((struct employee*)secondList.head->data)->name);   //cast to type struct employee
      printf("Employee2: %s\n", ((struct employee*)secondList.tail->data)->name);  
    }
```

Why does the answer that I posted below solve my problem? I believe it has something to do with pointers and memory allocation. The function Malloc() that i use is a custom malloc that checks for NULL being returned.

Here is a link to my entire generic linked list implementation: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13007/c-linked-list-implementation

Comment: If you run this in the debugger, you will learn which line causes the error.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: `emp->name = "Dan";`????  Shouldn't it be `strcpy(emp->name, "Dan")`?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: [Ted](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1637725/)?  A guaranteed ["Exercise in Poor Taste"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink_Flamingos) ;)

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth good suggestion with the strcpy... I will never be entirely used to C...

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus - Uh, that was *my* suggestion about strcpy().  And if you're curious about the "Ted" reference, look at Oli Charlesworth's avatar.  I asked him about it before, but he's been conspicuously silent...

Comment: @paulsm4 thank you then. However, it still does not solve my bus error. Any more suggestions?

Comment: "Shouldn't it be strcpy(emp->name, "Dan")? " -- only if you're intent on writing into unallocated memory.

Comment: Read the text under the bounty. That is what I am interested in.

Comment: It's confusing that the question has the relevant asked-about code in an answer. @CodeKingPlusPlus the code you're asking about should be in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is this accList_allocate() and your use of it.

```
struct accList secondList;
accList_allocate(&secondList);
```

In the original test2() secondList is memory on the stack.  &secondList is a pointer to that memory.  When you call accList_allocate() a copy of the pointer is passed in pointing at the stack memory.  Malloc() then returns a chunk of memory and assigns it to the copy of the pointer, not the original secondList.

Coming back out, secondList is still pointing at uninitialised memory on the stack so the call to appendToEnd() fails.

The same happens with the answer except secondList just happens to be free of junk.  Possibly by chance, possibly by design of the compiler.  Either way it is not something you should rely on.

Either:

```
struct accList *secondList = NULL;

accList_allocate(&secondList);
```

And change accList_allocate()

```
accList_allocate(struct accList **theList) {
    *theList = Malloc(sizeof(struct accList));
    (*theList)->head = NULL;
    (*theList)->tail = NULL;
    (*theList)->size = 0;
}
```

OR

```
struct accList secondList;

accList_initialise(secondList);
```

With accList_allocate() changed to accList_initialise() because it does not allocate

```
accList_initialise(struct accList *theList) {
    theList->head = NULL;
    theList->tail = NULL;
    theList->size = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is this:

1. You've allocated `secondList` on the stack in your original `test2` function.
2. The stack memory is probably dirty, so `secondList` requires initialization
3. Your `accList_allocate` function takes a pointer to the list, but then overwrites it with the `Malloc` call.  This means that the pointer you passed in is **never** initialized.
4. When `test2` tries to run, it hits a bad pointer (because the memory isn't initialized).

The reason that it works when you allocate it in `main` is that your C compiler probably zeros the stack when the program starts.  When `main` allocates a variable on the stack, that allocation is persistent (until the program ends), so `secondList` is actually, and accidentally, properly initialized when you allocate it in `main`.

Your current `accList_allocate` doesn't actually initialize the pointer that's been passed in, and the rest of your code will never see the pointer that it allocates with `Malloc`.  To solve your problem, I would create a new function: `accList_initialize` whose only job is to initialize the list:

```
void accList_initialize(struct accList* theList)
{
    // NO malloc
   theList->head = NULL;
   theList->tail = NULL;
   theList->size = 0;
}
```

Use this, instead of `accList_allocate` in your original `test2` function.  If you really want to allocate the list on the heap, then you should do so (and not mix it with a struct allocated on the stack).  Have `accList_allocate` **return** a pointer to the allocated structure:

```
struct accList* accList_allocate(void)
{
   struct accList* theList = Malloc( sizeof(struct accList) );
   accList_initialize(theList);
   return theList;
}
```

Comment: One way to verify that this is correct is to print the data structures out after allocating them on the stack, but before calling `accList_allocate`.  Use something like `printf("size=%lu  head=%p  tail=%p\n", secondList->size, secondList->head, secondList->tail);`.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on how your Employee structure is designed, but you should note that

```
strcpy(emp->name, "Dan");
```

and

```
emp->name = "Dan";
```

function differently.  In particular, the latter is a likely source of bus errors because you generally cannot write to string literals in this way.  Especially if your code has something like

name = "NONE"

or the like.

EDIT:  Okay, so with the design of the employee struct, the problem is this:

You can't assign to arrays.  The C Standard includes a list of modifiable lvalues and arrays are not one of them.

```
char name[20];
name = "JAMES" //illegal
```

strcpy is fine - it just goes to the memory address dereferenced by name[0] and copies "JAMES\0" into the memory there, one byte at a time.

Comment: My answer uses strcpy. I am looking for why my answer solves my problem. I believe it has something to do with pointers and allocation. 'My answer' is posted as a literal stack overflow answer.

Comment: I'm trying to answer that question but you left the critical part (the design of the employee structure) out.  Your answer also implies that the fix came from re-arranging the scope of the memory allocations ("When I place the declaration and allocation of secondList in main() and put the rest in a function it works").

Comment: Okay, the format of the structure you have makes the problem more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I see wrong here based on the original code, in the above question,

What you've seen is undefined behaviour and arose from that is the bus error message as you were assigning a string literal to the variable, when in fact you should have been using the `strcpy` function, you've edited your original code accordinly so.. something to keep in mind in the future :)

The usage of the word `Malloc` is going to cause confusion, especially in peer-review, the reviewers are going to have a brain fart and say "whoa, what's this, should that not be malloc?" and very likely raise it up. (Basically, do not call custom functions that have similar sounding names as the C standard library functions)

You're not checking for the `NULL`, what if your souped up version of `Malloc` failed then `emp` is going to be `NULL`! Always check it no matter how trivial or your thinking is "Ah sher the platform has heaps of memory on it, 4GB RAM no problem, will not bother to check for NULL"

Have a look at [this question posted elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212466/what-is-a-bus-error) to explain what is a bus error.

***Edit:*** Using linked list structures, in how the parameters in the function is called is crucial to the understanding of it. Notice the usage of **&**, meaning *take the address of the variable that points to the linked list structure*, and **passing it by reference**, not **passing by value** which is a copy of the variable. This same rule applies to usage of pointers also in general :)

You've got the parameters slightly out of place in the first code in your question, if you were using double-pointers in the parameter list then yes, using `&secondList` would have worked.

Comment: I just posted what Malloc does, it just checks for NULL. Read the text underneath the bounty and relay your answer to that text...

Comment: No, this is so I can have generic linked lists and for practice. The next step will be deallocating 'object types' in the list when I free a node in the list. I was going to use a function pointer to the objects deallocate function.