# Bus error when trying to write in shared memory

Tags: c++, c, linux, x86-64

I try to use shared memory with **shm_open** and **mmap**. However, whenever I try to write to that memory, I get bus error. The minimalist example code is given below. What is the problem here and how can it be solved?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

// compile with -lrt

char fname[64];
int fd;

int main()
{
    int * sm;
    sprintf( fname, "%d_%u", 4, 4 ); 

    if ((fd = shm_open(fname, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0777)) == -1)
    {        
        perror(NULL);
        return 0;
    }
    sm = (int*)mmap(0, (size_t)4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_FILE|MAP_SHARED, 
      fd, 0);
    printf( "Now trying to see if it works!\n" );
    sm[0] = 42;
    printf( "%d, %d!\n", sm[0], sm[1] );

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is the following

```
Now trying to see if it works!
Bus error
```

Comment: You need to check if `mmap` returns `MAP_FAILED` and, if so, consult `errno` to figure out why. (Also, you wouldn't be trying to write to a zero-length shared object, would you? Neither `mmap`, nor a write to an `mmap` area, can enlarge an object.)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212466/what-is-a-bus-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A newly-created object has a size of zero. You cannot change the size of an object by mapping it or writing to its mapping. You probably need to call `ftruncate` before `mmap`. (If your code had error-checking, this would be much easier to figure out.)

Comment: In this case error checking doesn't matter as mmap will happily map a zero length file, as long as length is page aligned.