# Why is this C code giving me a bus error?

Tags: c, arrays, function, bus-error

I have, as usual, been reading quite a few posts on here. I found a particular useful posts on bus errors in general, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212466/what-is-a-bus-error). My problem is that I cannot understand why my particular code is giving me an error.

My code is an attempt to teach myself C. It's a modification of a game I made when I learned Java. The goal in my game is to take a huge 5049 x 1 text file of words. Randomly pick a word, jumble it and try to guess it. I know how to do all of that. So anyway, each line of the text file contains a word like:

```
   5049
   must
   lean 
   better 
   program 
   now
   ...
```

So, I created an string array in C, tried to read this string array and put it into C. I didn't do anything else. Once I get the file into C, the rest should be easy. Weirder yet is that it complies. My problem comes when I run it with `./blah` command.

The error I get is simple. It says:

```
zsh: bus error ./blah
```

My code is below. I suspect it might have to do with memory or overflowing the buffer, but that's completely unscientific and a gut feeling. So my question is simple, why is this C code giving me this bus error msg?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//Preprocessed Functions 
void jumblegame();
void readFile(char* [], int);


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    jumblegame();

}

void jumblegame()
{
    //Load File 
        int x = 5049; //Rows
        int y = 256; //Colums
        char* words[x]; 
        readFile(words,x);

    //Define score variables 
        int totalScore = 0;
        int currentScore = 0; 

   //Repeatedly pick a random work, randomly jumble it, and let the user guess what it is

}

void readFile(char* array[5049], int x) 
{
    char line[256]; //This is to to grab each string in the file and put it in a line. 
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("words.txt","r");

    //Check to make sure file can open 
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: File does not open.");
        exit(1);
    }
    //Otherwise, read file into array  
    else
    {
        while(!feof(file))//The file will loop until end of file
        {
           if((fgets(line,256,file))!= NULL)//If the line isn't empty
           {
               array[x] = fgets(line,256,file);//store string in line x of array 
               x++; //Increment to the next line 
           }    
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line has a few problems:

```
array[x] = fgets(line,256,file);//store string in line x of array
```

- You've already read the line  in the condition of the immediately preceding `if` statement: the current line that you want to operate on is **already** in the buffer and now you use `fgets` to get the *next* line.
- You're trying to assign to the same array slot each time: instead you'll want to keep a separate variable for the array index that increments each time through the loop.
- Finally, you're trying to copy the strings using `=`. This will only copy references, it won't make a new copy of the string. So each element of the array will point to the same buffer: `line`, which will go out of scope and become invalid when your function exits. To populate your `array` with the strings, you need to make a copy of each one for the array: allocate space for each new string using `malloc`, then use [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) to copy each `line` into your new string. Alternately, if you can use [`strdup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html), it will take care of allocating the space for you.

But I suspect that this is the cause of your bus error: you're passing in the array *size* as `x`, and in your loop, you're assigning to `array[x]`. The problem with this is that `array[x]` doesn't belong to the array, the array only has useable indices of `0` to `(x - 1)`.

Comment: array[] doesn't exist anyway :(

Comment: Just to clarify, the pointer you're writing into `array[x]` currently is a pointer to `line`.  `line` is deallocated when `readFile` returns, making those pointers all invalid.

Comment: Thanks. This answered my question. I also used the following link to figure out how to copy a string to an array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088622/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-strings-in-c

Comment: I have to admit, this is a little bit like black magic to me since I am learning about buffers, malloc, and all this stuff that java and C# do automatically. Can you recommend a good reading source or book that explains these in C to me? Otherwise, I feel I am just using black magic and not understanding the principles of C well. :-(

Comment: You gotta figure out pointers to use C. I recommend Kernighan&Ritchie's [_The C Programming Language_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language), [see also](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/). It's a small book, but packed with useful information. Do all the exercises, and this won't seem so esoteric. This book _is_ dated, but it remains very useful, and no C text that I've seen is more succinct. Also, see the `pointers` section from [this tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson6.html)

Comment: Thank you. I did some google searches on data structures as well in C. But do you have any favorites?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the value 5049 for x.  The first time that the line

```
array[x] = ...
```

executes, it's accessing an array location that does not exist.

It looks like you are learning C.  Great!  A skill you need to master early is basic debugger use.  In this case, if you compile your program with

```
gcc -g myprogram.c -o myprogram
```

and then run it with

```
gdb ./myprogram
```

(I am assuming Linux), you will get a stack dump that shows the line where bus error occurred.  This should be enough to help you figure out the error yourself, which in the long run is much better than asking others.

There are many other ways a debugger is useful, but this is high on the list.  It gives you a window into your running program.

Comment: Thank you. I just googled gdb and ran it. It reported memory problem in readfile, which was a general clue to what specifically has been pointed out wrong above, which is my use of fget(). Working on fix now. (I am learning how to use linux and unix, plus vim).

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the lines in the line buffer, which is defined inside the readFile function, and storing pointers to it in the arary. There are two problems with that: you are overwriting the value everytime a new string is read and the buffer is in the stack, and is invalid once the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least a few problems:

- `array[x] = fgets(line,256,file)`

  This stores the address of `line` into each array element. `line` in no longer valid when `readFile()` returns, so you'll have an array of of useless pointers.  Even if `line` had a longer lifetime, it wouldn't be useful to have all your array elements having the same pointer (they'd each just point to whatever happened to be written in the buffer last)
- `while(!feof(file))`

  This is an antipattern for reading a file. See http://c-faq.com/stdio/feof.html and ["Using feof() incorrectly"](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/common-c-errors.php#4.2).  This antipattern is likely responsible for your program  looping more than you might expect when reading the file.
- you allocate the array to hold 5049 pointers, but you simply read however much is in the file - there's no checking for whether or not you read the expected number or to prevent reading too many.  You should think about allocating the array dynamically as you read the file  or have a mechanism to ensure you read the right amount of data (not too little and not too much) and handle the error when it's not right.

Comment: That made my heart sink when I saw I could be using feof not correctly. I probably will tinker around with a way to get this work using fread directly. And I prefer to do things dynamically, but was told by a friend that C is often about just putting in numbers that "work". Starting to sound like I got bad advice.

Comment: Putting in numbers that "work" can be OK, but there should be error handling in place for when the data exceeds those numbers (or when the data doesn't reach the expected number if that's important).

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the problem is with `(fgets(line,256,file))!=NULL)`. A better way to read a file is with `fread()` (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/). Specify the `FILE*` (a file stream in C), the size of the buffer, and the buffer. The routine returns the number of bytes read. If the return value is zero, then the EOF has been reached.

```
char buff [256]; 
fread (file, sizeof(char), 256, buff);
```

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try this once I get my program working the current way I have it. I feel this may indeed be a better solution.