# mmap Bus Error writing to MAP_SHARED file over 2Gb

Tags: c, linux, mmap, sigbus

I am trying to create a memory mapped file using MAP_SHARED.  I run into issues when the file size reaches 2gb.  The code pasted below is what I am using (as a test).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define MY_FILE "/dev/shm/mmap_test"
#define BLOCK_SIZE (1024*1024)
#define NUM_FILES 1

void mk_file(int f_num)
{ 
    uint64_t len = 0;
    int fd, j, k;
    char tmp_file[1024], *x, *rr_addr;

    // Open file in /dev/shm
    sprintf(tmp_file, "%s%d", MY_FILE, f_num);
    fd = open(tmp_file, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);

    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("file open");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // 16Gb file 
    len = 16UL * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    printf("len: %ld Gb\n", len/(1024*1024*1024));

    printf("Mapping %ld blocks\n", len/BLOCK_SIZE);

    for (j = 0; j < len/BLOCK_SIZE; j++) {
        // Increase the file size
        ftruncate(fd, ((j + 1) * BLOCK_SIZE));

        // Just mmap memory... don't have file backing
        //rr_addr = mmap(NULL, BLOCK_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON|MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0);

        // MMAP a region to the file at a given offset
        rr_addr = mmap(NULL, BLOCK_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_NORESERVE, fd, (j * BLOCK_SIZE));

        if (rr_addr == MAP_FAILED) {
            perror("mmap error");
            printf("INDEX: %d\n", j);
            exit(-1);
        }

        // Write to every byte of allocated memory
        x = (char *) rr_addr;

        for (k = 0; k < BLOCK_SIZE; k++)
        {
            *x = '1';
            x++;
        }
    }

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    uint64_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_FILES; i++)
       mk_file(i);

    return 0;
}
```

In the code above, I get a bus error when the offset in the file reaches 2gb.  These are the things I have tried:

1. If I change NUM_FILES to 16 and len to 1GB, I don't have any issues.
2. If I remove the for loop which writes to the memory (only mmap), the program does not crash (even for len much greater than 2gb) b/c the linux kernel does not actually map pages to the file until you read/write to the mmap'ed region.
3. If I change the mmap call from MAP_SHARED to MAP_ANON (uncomment the first mmap call and comment out the second one) and not linked to a file, there are no issues (even the writes succeed).
4. There is enough space on /dev/shm (30gb), I am using only 16gb here.
5. I don't have to write to every allocated byte.  I only need to write to the last mmap'ed region (move the inner for loop outside) and if the offset + BLOCK_SIZE >= 2gb then I get a bus error.
6. I have tried this on Ubuntu 13.10 and CentOS 6.4 and both have the same issue.

I am wondering if this is an issue in the linux kernel?  Has anyone tried mmap'ing a single file using MAP_SHARED greater than 2gb and used (read/write to) it successfully?

Comment: I assume you're on a 64-bit system?

Comment: Yes I am.  The issue was, as mentioned in the selected answer below, that the file length for `ftruncate` was overflowing and not extending the file.  Changing the definition of `j` to a `uint64_t` from `int` resolved my issue.  Since the `ftruncate` failed, the adding the files to that offset also failed which was resulting in a `SIGBUS`.

Comment: If it's a problem with physical memory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391933/how-to-handle-bus-error-for-accessing-mmap-ed-memory-when-underlying-physical-me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `j` is an `int`. When `j` hits large values, `(j + 1) * BLOCK_SIZE` overflows and your `ftruncate` call does not do what you intend. Checking the return value from `ftruncate` should confirm this.

The [mmap man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) specifically calls out `SIGBUS` as meaning that the attempted access is not backed by the file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps in your case. When we had problems with big files the following helped. We have put the macro:

```
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
```

before including standard headers. You can define it also on command line when invoking gcc.

Comment: This is necessary for 32-bit systems only.