# What are the possible reasons for POSIX SIGBUS?

Tags: c++, signals, posix

My program recently crashed with the following stack;

```
Program terminated with signal 7, Bus error.
#0  0x00007f0f323beb55 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f0f323beb55 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f0f35f8042e in skgesigOSCrash () from /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
#2  0x00007f0f36222ca9 in kpeDbgSignalHandler () from /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
#3  0x00007f0f35f8063e in skgesig_sigactionHandler () from /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
#4  <signal handler called>
```

What should I check in my code to avoid this? Or is this something Oracle should fix?

Comment: What is the argument to `raise`? `SIGBUS`?

Answer (score 2):

Main reasons you could get a *bus error* revolves around *inaccessible memory*. This could be due to many reasons:

- Accessing through a deleted pointer.
- Accessing through an uninitialized pointer.
- Accessing through a NULL pointer.
- Accessing the address which is not yours. It could be due to overflow errors.

Comment: or is this something oracle should fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the *$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/*.ora* file:

```
DIAG_ADR_ENABLED=OFF
DIAG_SIGHANDLER_ENABLED=FALSE
DIAG_DDE_ENABLED=FALSE
```

This sounds like an Oracle issue.

And also Oracle's libraries seem to be compiled by Intel compilers.