# Android ARM64 unaligned access

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm64

Do Android versions >= 5.0 guarantee anything about ARM64 processors allowing unaligned access? Or is there at least an implicit guarantee based on how Linux is configured?

I know that 32-bit ARM does not allow it, but I'm only interested in 64-bit. I also know about the limitations and performance implications of unaligned access. My question is simply if unaligned access does happen on ARM64 Android, because of a porting mistake from x86-64 code, is that probably OK or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does AArch64 support unaligned access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38535738/does-aarch64-support-unaligned-access)

Comment: @Siguza No. I know it *can* support it, why else would I be asking the question. The question is if Android is configured to support it or not.