# to_upper program does not compile due to bus error in C

Tags: c

I have a simple function that should convert lowercase characters to uppercase. But at a certain point, I get a bus error. **What does this error mean** and how can it be fixed?

PS I've been trying to figure out what this error means for a long time and as a result I can't figure out what the difference is between *bus error* and *segmentation fault*

```
void *to_upper(const char *str) {
    char *strCopy = (char *)str;

    int strLength = strlen(strCopy);

    for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {
        if (strCopy[i] >= 'a' && strCopy[i] <= 'z') {
            strCopy[i] = (int)strCopy[i] - 32; // ERROR -> zsh: bus error  ./a.out
        }
    }

    return strCopy;
}
```

- 

```
printf("to_upper: %s", (char *)to_upper("TeSt"));
```

Comment: First of all, `char *strCopy = (char *)str;` doesn't create a copy of the actual string, it just creates a copy of the *pointer* to the first character of the string. Secondly, literal strings are non-modifiable, any attempt to modify a literal string leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And if you want to return a pointer to `char`, why do you set the return-type to `void *`? That you need to cast the returned pointer is a sign you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Lastly, when you run a program, all code in it has already passed the compiler, and it could be days, months or years between compilation and running. From source to running a program there are multiple steps: 1) Edit source; 2) Compile source into object files; 3) Link object files with libraries to create the executable program file; And 4) Run the executable program file. Your crash happens in step 4.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude about the function and the return type. This is spelled out in the task: void *to_upper(const char *str), Returns a copy of string (str) converted to uppercase. In case of any error, return NULL

Maybe I misunderstood something and am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212466/what-is-a-bus-error-is-it-different-from-a-segmentation-fault) for an answer to "how does a bus error differ from a segmentation violation".

As to why you're getting a bus error in your case, you're effectively modifying a string literal, as Some programmer dude said in a comment on your OP. Here's why:

1. You call your function with "TeSt" as an argument.
2. The function parameter `str` gets assigned the location of the string literal "TeSt", which is located in in unmodifiable region of your program.
3. You say `char *strCopy = (char *) str`, which is saying that `strCopy` should point to the same location as `str`. If you want to actually copy the string, use `strdup(str)` instead.
4. When you say `strCopy[i] = ...`, because of the above, this is trying to change values in a memory region you don't have access to. That's why you get a bus error.