# tts model killing python with `zsh: bus error python Neural_Audio_Synthesis.py`

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-to-speech, coqui

I have a simple script trying to run tts on a Apple M1 Pro with MACOS 13.2.1

from this repo https://github.com/coqui-ai/TTS

```
def audio_Synth():
    from TTS.api import TTS
    import numpy as np
    import random
    # Running a multi-speaker and multi-lingual model
    print("testing....")
    models_list = TTS.list_models()
    # List available TTS models and choose the first one
    model_name = TTS.list_models()[17]
    print(model_name)
    print("testing....")
    # Init TTS
    tts = TTS(model_name)
    
    # Text to speech to a file
    # tts.tts_to_file(text=text, speaker=tts.speakers[int(voice_selected)], language = tts.languages, file_path=video_id+".wav")

audio_Synth()
```

When I run the code I get this error

```
testing....
tts_models/en/vctk/vits
testing....
 > tts_models/en/vctk/vits is already downloaded.
 > Using model: vits
 > Setting up Audio Processor...
 | > sample_rate:22050
 | > resample:False
 | > num_mels:80
 | > log_func:np.log10
 | > min_level_db:0
 | > frame_shift_ms:None
 | > frame_length_ms:None
 | > ref_level_db:None
 | > fft_size:1024
 | > power:None
 | > preemphasis:0.0
 | > griffin_lim_iters:None
 | > signal_norm:None
 | > symmetric_norm:None
 | > mel_fmin:0
 | > mel_fmax:None
 | > pitch_fmin:None
 | > pitch_fmax:None
 | > spec_gain:20.0
 | > stft_pad_mode:reflect
 | > max_norm:1.0
 | > clip_norm:True
 | > do_trim_silence:False
 | > trim_db:60
 | > do_sound_norm:False
 | > do_amp_to_db_linear:True
 | > do_amp_to_db_mel:True
 | > do_rms_norm:False
 | > db_level:None
 | > stats_path:None
 | > base:10
 | > hop_length:256
 | > win_length:1024
zsh: bus error  python Neural_Audio_Synthesis.py
```

I've tried to update the libraries and setting values in the method. I tired to run with iterm as well as terminal.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'm running Python 3.9.6

here are my pip versions

```
(venv) TVarug000@RESML-1731542 50-Facts-Projects % pip list
Package                                           Version     Editable project location
------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------------------------------------
aiohttp                                           3.8.3
aiosignal                                         1.3.1
anyascii                                          0.3.1
apiclient                                         1.0.4
appdirs                                           1.4.4
async-generator                                   1.10
async-timeout                                     4.0.2
attrs                                             22.2.0
audioread                                         3.0.0
audiotsm                                          0.1.2
Babel                                             2.11.0
beautifulsoup4                                    4.11.1
cachetools                                        5.2.1
certifi                                           2022.12.7
cffi                                              1.15.1
charset-normalizer                                2.1.1
click                                             8.1.3
colorama                                          0.4.6
comtypes                                          1.1.14
contourpy                                         1.0.7
coqpit                                            0.0.17
cycler                                            0.11.0
Cython                                            0.29.28
datasets                                          2.8.0
dateparser                                        1.1.7
decorator                                         4.4.2
dill                                              0.3.6
docopt                                            0.6.2
espeakng                                          1.0.2
evaluate                                          0.4.0
exceptiongroup                                    1.1.0
ffmpeg                                            1.4
filelock                                          3.9.0
Flask                                             2.2.2
fonttools                                         4.38.0
frozenlist                                        1.3.3
fsspec                                            2023.1.0
g2pkk                                             0.1.2
google                                            3.0.0
google-api-core                                   2.11.0
google-api-python-client                          2.73.0
google-auth                                       2.16.0
google-auth-httplib2                              0.1.0
googleapis-common-protos                          1.58.0
gruut                                             2.2.3
gruut-ipa                                         0.13.0
gruut-lang-de                                     2.0.0
gruut-lang-en                                     2.0.0
gTTS                                              2.3.1
h11                                               0.14.0
httplib2                                          0.21.0
huggingface-hub                                   0.11.1
idna                                              3.4
imageio                                           2.24.0
imageio-ffmpeg                                    0.4.8
importlib-metadata                                6.0.0
inflect                                           5.6.0
itsdangerous                                      2.1.2
jamo                                              0.4.1
jieba                                             0.42.1
Jinja2                                            3.1.2
joblib                                            1.2.0
jsonlines                                         1.2.0
kiwisolver                                        1.4.4
librosa                                           0.8.0
llvmlite                                          0.38.1
MarkupSafe                                        2.1.2
matplotlib                                        3.6.3
mecab-python3                                     1.0.5
MouseInfo                                         0.1.3
moviepy                                           1.0.3
multidict                                         6.0.4
multiprocess                                      0.70.14
networkx                                          2.8.8
nltk                                              3.8.1
num2words                                         0.5.12
numba                                             0.55.1
numpy                                             1.21.6
oauth2client                                      4.1.3
openai                                            0.26.1
opencv-python                                     4.7.0.68
outcome                                           1.2.0
packaging                                         23.0
pandas                                            1.5.3
Pillow                                            9.4.0
pip                                               23.0.1
pooch                                             1.6.0
proglog                                           0.1.10
progressbar2                                      4.2.0
protobuf                                          3.19.6
psutil                                            5.9.4
pyarrow                                           10.0.1
pyasn1                                            0.4.8
pyasn1-modules                                    0.2.8
PyAutoGUI                                         0.9.53
pycparser                                         2.21
pydub                                             0.25.1
PyGetWindow                                       0.0.9
PyMsgBox                                          1.0.9
pynndescent                                       0.5.8
pyobjc                                            9.0.1
pyobjc-core                                       9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-Accessibility                    9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-Accounts                         9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook                      9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-AdServices                       9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-AdSupport                        9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit                   9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC                  9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-ApplicationServices              9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-AppTrackingTransparency          9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-AudioVideoBridging               9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-AuthenticationServices           9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-AutomaticAssessmentConfiguration 9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-Automator                        9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-AVFoundation                     9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-AVKit                            9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-AVRouting                        9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-BackgroundAssets                 9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-BusinessChat                     9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CalendarStore                    9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CallKit                          9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork                        9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-ClassKit                         9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CloudKit                         9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa                            9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration                    9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-ColorSync                        9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-Contacts                         9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-ContactsUI                       9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreAudio                        9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreAudioKit                     9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreBluetooth                    9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreData                         9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreHaptics                      9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation                     9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreMedia                        9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreMediaIO                      9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreMIDI                         9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreML                           9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreMotion                       9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreServices                     9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreSpotlight                    9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreText                         9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreWLAN                         9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-CryptoTokenKit                   9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-DataDetection                    9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-DeviceCheck                      9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices               9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-DiscRecording                    9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-DiscRecordingUI                  9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-DiskArbitration                  9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-DVDPlayback                      9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-EventKit                         9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling                9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-ExecutionPolicy                  9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-ExtensionKit                     9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-ExternalAccessory                9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-FileProvider                     9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-FileProviderUI                   9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-FinderSync                       9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents                         9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-GameCenter                       9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-GameController                   9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-GameKit                          9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-GameplayKit                      9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-HealthKit                        9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-ImageCaptureCore                 9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-IMServicePlugIn                  9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit                   9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins                 9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage                   9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-Intents                          9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-IntentsUI                        9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-IOSurface                        9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-iTunesLibrary                    9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-KernelManagement                 9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping            9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices                   9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-libdispatch                      9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-LinkPresentation                 9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-LocalAuthentication              9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-LocalAuthenticationEmbeddedUI    9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-MailKit                          9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-MapKit                           9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-MediaAccessibility               9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-MediaLibrary                     9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-MediaPlayer                      9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-MediaToolbox                     9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-Metal                            9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-MetalFX                          9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-MetalKit                         9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-MetalPerformanceShaders          9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-MetalPerformanceShadersGraph     9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-MetricKit                        9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-MLCompute                        9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-ModelIO                          9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-MultipeerConnectivity            9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-NaturalLanguage                  9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-NetFS                            9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-Network                          9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-NetworkExtension                 9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-NotificationCenter               9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory                    9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-OSAKit                           9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-OSLog                            9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-PassKit                          9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-PencilKit                        9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-Photos                           9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-PhotosUI                         9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes                  9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-PushKit                          9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-Quartz                           9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-QuickLookThumbnailing            9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-ReplayKit                        9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-SafariServices                   9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-SafetyKit                        9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-SceneKit                         9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-ScreenCaptureKit                 9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver                      9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-ScreenTime                       9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge                  9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit                        9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-Security                         9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-SecurityFoundation               9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-SecurityInterface                9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement                9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-SharedWithYou                    9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-SharedWithYouCore                9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-ShazamKit                        9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-Social                           9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-SoundAnalysis                    9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-Speech                           9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-SpriteKit                        9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-StoreKit                         9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices                     9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration              9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-SystemExtensions                 9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-ThreadNetwork                    9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-UniformTypeIdentifiers           9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-UserNotifications                9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-UserNotificationsUI              9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-VideoSubscriberAccount           9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-VideoToolbox                     9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-Virtualization                   9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-Vision                           9.0.1
pyobjc-framework-WebKit                           9.0.1
pyparsing                                         3.0.9
pyperclip                                         1.8.2
pypexels                                          1.0.0rc1
pypinyin                                          0.48.0
PyRect                                            0.2.0
pysbd                                             0.3.4
PyScreeze                                         0.1.28
pyser                                             0.1.5
PySocks                                           1.7.1
python-crfsuite                                   0.9.9
python-dateutil                                   2.8.2
python-utils                                      3.5.2
pyttsx3                                           2.90
pytweening                                        1.0.4
pytz                                              2022.7.1
pytz-deprecation-shim                             0.1.0.post0
pyworld                                           0.3.2
PyYAML                                            6.0
regex                                             2022.10.31
requests                                          2.28.2
resampy                                           0.4.2
responses                                         0.18.0
rsa                                               4.9
rubicon-objc                                      0.4.5
scikit-learn                                      1.2.1
scipy                                             1.10.0
selenium                                          4.7.2
setuptools                                        58.0.4
simple-youtube-api                                0.2.8
six                                               1.16.0
sniffio                                           1.3.0
sortedcontainers                                  2.4.0
soundfile                                         0.11.0
soupsieve                                         2.3.2.post1
summarizer                                        0.0.7
tensorboardX                                      2.5.1
textrazor                                         1.4.0
threadpoolctl                                     3.1.0
tokenizers                                        0.13.2
torch                                             1.13.1
torchaudio                                        0.13.1
tqdm                                              4.64.1
trainer                                           0.0.20
transformers                                      4.25.1
trio                                              0.22.0
trio-websocket                                    0.9.2
TTS                                               0.11.1      /Users/TVarug000/Development/Youtube/TTS
typing_extensions                                 4.4.0
tzdata                                            2022.7
tzlocal                                           4.2
umap-learn                                        0.5.1
unidic-lite                                       1.0.8
uritemplate                                       4.1.1
urllib3                                           1.26.14
Werkzeug                                          2.2.2
wsproto                                           1.2.0
xxhash                                            3.2.0
yarl                                              1.8.2
zipp                                              3.12.1
```

I've tired different versions of python and I also tried to upgrade libraries.

Comment: What hardware are you running this on? What is the "TTS" library? I see that unlike all your other libraries, it is installed in a custom directory. Please edit your question to include this information, and add a tag for whichever library "TTS" is, if one exists.

Comment: I updated - but i will post here as well. The code is from this repo https://github.com/coqui-ai/TTS
Apple M1 Pro with MACOS 13.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/coqui-ai/TTS/issues/2052#issuecomment-1273044171) on an isuse on [the TTS GitHub](https://github.com/coqui-ai/TTS), M1 Macs are not supported as of October 2022.

This explanation aligns with the `zsh: bus error  python Neural_Audio_Synthesis.py` error that you were getting. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/212585/4374594),

> Bus errors are rare nowadays on x86 and occur when your processor cannot even attempt the memory access requested, typically when using a processor instruction with an address that does not satisfy its alignment requirements.

I only briefly looked at the GitHub, so you may want to do some research or open a new issue there regarding M1 support. However, at the least, it seems that the version you have installed now does not support the M1 processor.